# How to read values from multiple sheets in excel with openpyxl

Tags: python, openpyxl

I have two sheets in one excel file. And I want to read the two values from the two excel sheets.

SO I try it like this:

```
import openpyxl


path = "./docs/hoi.xlsx"


wb_obj = openpyxl.load_workbook(path, data_only=True)

sheet_names = [' Overzicht Noord ', 'Overzicht Midden']

for i in sheet_names:     
    sheet_obj = wb_obj[i]
    cell_obj = sheet_obj.cell(row = 6, column = 8).value

print(cell_obj)
```

But it only returns one value from one sheet. And not the two values from the two sheets.

My question is: how to return the two values from the two sheets?

Comment: you are assigning it to the same variable - `cell_obj`. can you move the `print` inside the loop and try?

Comment: ah, oke. yes, that was stupid of me. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are assigning it to the same variable - `cell_obj`. Please move the `print` inside the loop.